# Error importing jpype: can't apply this __setattr__ to _jpype._JClass object

Tags: java, python, jpype

Can't apply this **setattr** to _jpype._JClass object

When I'm importing type I'm getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import jpype
  File "C:\Users\64837\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ._core import *
  File "C:\Users\64837\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import types as _jtypes
  File "C:\Users\64837\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\types.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ._jarray import *
  File "C:\Users\64837\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jarray.py", line 213, in <module>
    _jcustomizer._applyCustomizerPost(_jpype._JArray, _JArrayProto)
  File "C:\Users\64837\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jcustomizer.py", line 166, in _applyCustomizerPost
    _applyCustomizerImpl(cls.__dict__, proto, sticky,
  File "C:\Users\64837\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jcustomizer.py", line 148, in _applyCustomizerImpl
    setter(p, v)
  File "C:\Users\64837\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jcustomizer.py", line 167, in <lambda>
    lambda p, v: type.__setattr__(cls, p, v))
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to _jpype._JClass object
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJnhf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). – In particular you want to make it  easy for others to reproduce your problem, see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I work on Ubuntu. I have Python 3.8.5, and I also faced this problem having out-of-date jpype. Now the latest version of jpype is 1.0.2, I upgraded jpype to the latest version, and everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Python 3.8.4. Refer to this [mailchain](https://www.mail-archive.com/python-bugs-list@python.org/msg422258.html). Try downgrading to Python 3.8.3 in the meantime.